# Oracle Define New Spatial referance SRID

Tags: oracle, reference, oracle-spatial, gis

I have a wkt text about one spatial reference system. But I dont know how can I import this into oracle. Any one can help me to convert this wkt to srid for oracle spatial and transform actions. I use oracle 11g 
spatial wkt link : http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8775/

Comment: Did you check this: [Creating a User-Defined Coordinate Reference System](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28400/sdo_cs_concepts.htm#SPATL712)?

Comment: Have a look at [EPSG:5253](https://epsg.io/5253), I think most EPSG codes are already implemented in Oracle Spatial. Note, `ITRF96-IZMIR-TURKEY` uses "WGS84" whereas `EPSG:5253` uses "GRS80". However as long as your calculation do not take into account geophysical plate tectonics they can be considered as equal.

Comment: firstly thanks for your comments . secondly , I checked link that you mentioned  and I create a coordinate referance with defined information in oracle. which values I used are "VALUES (98776,'ITRF96 test','PROJECTED',4400,NULL,6326,4917,16369,NULL,NULL,'EPSG:8776',NULL,'FALSE',NULL,NULL,NULL,'TRUE','TRUE') ". unfortunetly there is 100 meter difference when convert 2319 to 98776. As a third epsg:5253 doesnt implemented by my oracle version. "ORA-13199: SRID does not exist."

Answer (score 1):

You did not say what exact version you are using, so I will assume 11.2 (11.2.0.3 or 11.2.0.4).

Can you try the following definition:

```
delete from sdo_coord_ref_system where srid=8775;
insert into sdo_coord_ref_system (
  SRID,
  COORD_REF_SYS_NAME,
  COORD_REF_SYS_KIND,
  GEOG_CRS_DATUM_ID,
  SOURCE_GEOG_SRID,
  IS_LEGACY,
  LEGACY_WKTEXT,
  IS_VALID,
  SUPPORTS_SDO_GEOMETRY 
)
values (
  8775,
  'ITRF96-IZMIR',
  'PROJECTED',
  1000000123,        
  1000000123,
  'TRUE',
  'PROJCS["ITRF96-IZMIR",GEOGCS ["WGS 84", DATUM ["World Geodetic System 1984", SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563]], PRIMEM [ "Greenwich", 0.000000], UNIT ["Decimal Degree", 0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting", 500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing", 0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",27.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1.0],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]]',
  'TRUE',           
  'TRUE'
);
commit;
```

There are actually two ways to define a new coordinate system in Oracle:

- One is to define it fully along the EPSG data model, i.e define the individual components (operation, operation method, parameter values)
- The other is to define it as a "legacy" coordinate system, by providing the WKT encoding.

Here I used the second technique since you had already the WKT. Note that I had to tweak it a bit to match the datum, projection, parameter names expected by Oracle.

Comment: Hi Albert ,firstly I use oracle 11.2 g. I tried technique that you told . When I had tried to convert 2319 to 8775 and reconvert to 2319 , I saw difference betwen two results.

Comment: here are results,  select sdo_cs.transform(sdo_cs.transform(sdo_geometry('POLYGON((509506.242146901 4251467.00163843,509496.251328023 4251466.53214178,509495.354600661 4251478.49845895
,509505.343578376 4251478.96552233,509506.242146901 4251467.00163843))',2319),8775),2319).Get_WKT() from dual , result = POLYGON ((509506.242446148 4251467.00256199, 509496.251627274 4251466.53306534, 509495.35489991 4251478.49938252, 509505.343877622 4251478.96644589, 509506.242446148 4251467.00256199)) .

Comment: Hmmm. That is interesting. Let me investigate. Then again the difference is less than 1/2 mm. Is this important for your application ?

Comment: such small difference is not a important. But when I overlay layers, I get an image like this https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/162082/1164664/t5ByjYv8apIuve1/upload.png , I suppose it is not 1/2 mm.

Comment: That is strange. You mean you have two tables, T1 and T2. T1 contains the original shapes in 2319, the other has the same shapes, transformed first to 8775 then back to 2319 ? Can you show the geometries for one of those shapes from both tables ?